# Cyclic navigation (Ctrl+F7) in eclipse application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, key-bindings

I would like to have a shortcut key implementation for cyclic navigation of the views like in Eclipse. In Eclipse , we can navigate to all the opened views in cyclic way using Ctrl+F7 key binding. How can I implement the same in my eclipse RCP application?

Comment: Is this an e4 or 3.x compatibility mode RCP?

Comment: this is 3.x mode

Comment: What Command is this keystroke bound to in the Keys preferences?

Comment: In eclipse , this is bound to 'Next View' command. But I want this keybinding to be implemented in my own application , not in Eclipse. I have created views using 'org.eclipse.ui.views' and want to add this key binding for these views. Is it possible?

Comment: If you are including the normal Eclipse view plugins you should just be able to use the same command `org.eclipse.ui.window.nextView` defined in the org.eclipse.ui` plugin

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command:

```
org.eclipse.ui.window.nextView
```